# Can JMeter be used to perform Functional testing?

Tags: testing, jmeter, functional-testing

I have used JMeter for performance testing of the web application. But I don't know how to use it for Functional testing.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

JMter can be used for functional testing for sure,please check the below sample for you to refer

http://www.packtpub.com/article/functional-testing-with-jmeter

http://www.testingminded.com/2009/02/tutorial-on-functional-testing-with_3268.html

Answer (score 2):

Jmeter can be used as functional testtool, but there is a challenge in maintenance your JMX file.

For example you are having a jmx file with 30 threads (for each different scenario 1, but with the same modules but with different variables). The functional tests ran fine.

Now the next release will have a change in a module. Then you need change all 30(!) threadgroups that module!!

This kind of maintenance can be annoying.

Comment: same scenario, have to use same ThreadGroup across multiple testplans to avoid duplication

Comment: @coding_idiot : Do you say, that the "ThreadGroup" is the resolution for the test-maintenance issue? ..just to clarify, as I am not experienced in that.

Comment: @Franta I don't recall much, but yes, I do remember using ThreadGroup for my usecase then.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's better to consider other tool for functional testing, for instance [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) browser automation framework perfectly suits as it supports all modern browsers.

JMeter has one major limitation - it isn't capable of executing JavaScript. However if you need to proceed with JMeter please consider following techniques to make it behavior more like to real browser:

1. Use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to hold cookies, deal with cookie-based authentication, etc.
2. Use [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send relevant headers like `User-Agent`, `Accept-Language`, etc.
3. Use [HTTP Cache Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to represent browser cache
4. Consider using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) Configuration Element for

   - asking JMeter to retrieve embedded resources to simulate a browser retrieving embedded resources (such as gifs, css, js etc).
   - using thread/connection pool to simulate the browser parallel fetching (use between 2-4).

You will also need to properly handle JavaScript-generated AJAX calls by creating relevant HTTP Requests which will simulate XMLHttp calls.

Comment: Actually, its better to consider doing as much of your functional integration testing below the UI with a tool like JMeter rather than trying to replicate the browser experience for every test.  Nothing against Selenium.  Its great if you want to do a small amount of GUI-level end-to-end tests, but you don't want the bulk of your business logic tested this way.  GUI automated tests are notoriously the slowest, most brittle, least maintainable automated tests you will create.  https://www.google.com/search?q=test+automation+pyramid